# error: nrow(ref) and nrow(target) must be > 0?

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

Based on [Unable to writeRaster for signature "rasterPCA", "character"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231134/unable-to-writeraster-for-signature-rasterpca-character), I obtained two rasters that are PC1 and PC2 of a bunch of climatic variables. However, irrespective of having the same extent and resolution, the number of cells differ in my global environment, when loaded into R.

Below is the code I am using, which is from the appendix of Hamann et al., 2015 and I get this error:

```
library(SDMTools)     # install package to read and write ESRI ASCII grids
library(yaImpute)     # install package for k-nearest neighbour (kNN) search

lg1 <- asc2dataframe("C:\\Users\\rameshv\\LGM\\4_PCAforR\\PC_1.asc") # principal component grids
lg2 <- asc2dataframe("C:\\Users\\rameshv\\LGM\\4_PCAforR\\PC_2.asc")
present1  <-asc2dataframe("C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Present\\4_PCAforR\\PC_1.asc")
present2  <- asc2dataframe("C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Present\\4_PCAforR\\PC_2.asc")

idxy <- cbind(id=1:nrow(lg1),lg1[,1:2])   # data frame of IDs and XY coords
b <- (max(lg1$var.1)-min(lg1$var.1))/120  # bin size for 120 PC1 bins

l1 <- round(lg1$var.1/b)              # convert PC1 to 120 bins via rounding
l2 <- round(lg2$var.1/b)              # convert PC2 to <120 bins via rounding
p1 <- round(present1$var.1/b)               # same for present PC1
p2 <- round(present2$var.1/b)               # same for present PC2
l  <- paste(l1,l2)                         # PC1/PC2 combinations in LGM climate
p  <- paste(p1,p2)                         # PC1/PC2 combinations in present climate
u  <- unique(p)[order(unique(p))]          # list of unique PC1/PC2 combinations

sid <- c()                                 # empty vector for source IDs
tid <- c()                                 # empty vector for target IDs
d   <- c()                                 # empty vector for distances

for(i in u){                          # loop for each unique PC1/PC2 combination
lxy <- idxy[which(l==i),]           # coordinates of i-th combination in LGM
pxy <- idxy[which(p==i),]           # coordinates of i-th combination in present
sid <- c(sid, lxy$id)               # append i-th PC1/PC2 combination to previous 

if(nrow(pxy)>0){                    # kNN search unless no-analogue climate
  knn <- data.frame(ann(as.matrix(pxy[,-1]), as.matrix(lxy[,-1]), k=1)$knnIndexDist)      
  tid <- c(tid, pxy[knn[,1],"id"]) # the IDs of the closest matches  
  d <- c(d, sqrt(knn[,2]))         # their corresponding geographic distances
}
 else {                              # else statement for no-analogue climates
 tid <- c(tid, rep(NA,nrow(lxy))) # flag destinations as missing for no analogues
 d <- c(d, rep(Inf,nrow(lxy)))    # flag distances as infinity for no analogues
 }
}
```

At the end of the for loop, I get the error below:

```
Error in ann(as.matrix(pxy[, -1]), as.matrix(lxy[, -1]), k = 1) : 
error: nrow(ref) and nrow(target) must be > 0
```

I am not sure if this error has something to do with difference in number of cells? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Based on Bastien's comment, I investigated the structure and I get this:

```
> str(as.matrix(pxy[,-1]))
  num [1:27, 1:2] 8.1 8.14 8.22 8.97 9.01 ...
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:27] "1" "8" "33" "583" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "y" "x"

> str(as.matrix(lxy[,-1]))
  logi[0 , 1:2] 
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "y" "x"
```

Suggestions?

Comment: The error is in the `ann` function from yaImpute which say that either your ref or your target set are of size 0.  Run `str(as.matrix(pxy[, -1]))`and `str(as.matrix(lxy[, -1]))` to be sure the structure is ok.  You may have a problem higher up in your data managment

Comment: @Bastien   That is interesting. You are right. I am getting the above currently. Added it to the edits. See above.

Comment: Did you check what you have in `l1` and `l2`?

Comment: @LoBu , yes, I checked them. They are all numeric and have values (none of them are empty).

Comment: looking at the code, it appears that some of your `u` s are not present in `l` (whatever those variables are). Thus `lxy <- idxy[which(l==i),]` gives probably a "bogus" result.

Comment: Here's the thing. I ran the same code, using different rasters having the same number of cells, and the code worked perfectly.

Comment: The entire point of that entire for loop is to find non-analogous values that are not present in l for each value of i.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the code just by reading it. However, if `ann(as.matrix(pxy[,-1]), as.matrix(lxy[,-1]), k=1)` "doesn't like" empty `lxy` arrays and  some of your `u` s are not present in `l`, it seems to me that your code will error, because `idxy[which(l==i),]` will return an empty array.

Comment: How do I correct that? some of them have zeros in them and some have negative values as well.

Comment: @poelinf ? Can you try taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

LoBu is correct that your `lxy` array is empty. It is not clear where this went wrong - your PCA may have failed, your bin size calculation of `b` may have failed. Your `pxy` data frame is also far too short, if you're trying to match binned climate values like in Hamann et al. 2015. Without seeing your data up close, it's not possible to say how to fix this problem - I would recommend checking your PCA outputs and the underlying climate rasters.

How big is your study area? Appendix 3 is by far the most complicated climate analog method. I would suggest trying Appendix 2, which is slower but works just fine if you're not working at high resolution. Here is the code, for quick reference.

```
library(SDMTools)       # install package to read and write ESRI ASCII grids
present <- asc2dataframe("C:\Your Path\MAT6190.asc")
future  <- asc2dataframe("C:\Your Path\MAT2020s.asc")

t <- 0.25               # plus/minus threshold to define climate match
t <- 1/(t*2)            # inverse for rounding, double for plus/minus

x <- present$x                    # vector of grid cell x coordinates
y <- present$y                    # vector of grid cell y coordinates
p <- round(present$var.1*t)/t     # vector of rounded present climate values 
f <- round(future$var.1*t)/t      # vector of rounded future climate values 
d <- vector(length=length(p))     # empty vector to write distance to climate match

u     <- unique(p)[order(unique(p))]    # list of unique climate values in p
match <- function(u){c(which(u==f))}    # function finding climate matches of u with f
m     <- sapply(u, match)               # list of climate matches for unique values

for(i in 1:length(p)){                  # loop for all grid cells of p
   mi   <- m[[which(u==p[i])]]          # recalls list of climate matches for p[i]
   d[i] <- sqrt(min((x[i]-x[mi])^2 + (y[i]-y[mi])^2))    # distance to closest match
   }

# writes out log10 speed and distance multiplied by 100 in ESRI ASCII format
# conversion: -200=0.01km, -100=0.1km, 0=1km, 100=10km, 200=100km etc.
d[d==Inf] <- 100000  # sets no analogue to 10,000km
out=cbind(y,x,logDist=round(log10(d)*100),logSpeed=round(log10(d/50)*100))
dataframe2asc(out)
```

Comment: Thanks @QBarber. Here's the thing. I have multiple climate variables and the resolution is not very high. It's around 5km by 5km. Basically running code from Appendix 2 would be done a single variable at a time right? How do you 'average' over all the climate velocity predictions then?               Also, with respect to the PCAs and the bin sizes, it works fine for me. Only difference between your sample data and my data is that I have about 50,000 elements, and you started off with 815345 number of elements. Does that matter?

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at the data Quinn? I can e-mail it to you.

Comment: Got it to work. There seems to have been a minor error in my for loop :)

Comment: Hi Vijay, glad you got it to work. 50,000 elements is well-suited for appendix 2, considering it is less efficient but easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks Quinn. Looks like appendix 3 was designed for a forward velocity calculation rather than a reverse, but I set the variables differently.